# Can't find module kafka

Tags: python, docker, kafka-python

I have a python project that employees Kafka Queues, the project runs as expected but fails to run when run as part of a docker container.It keeps throwing this error `can't find the module kafka`

This is how my Dockerfile..

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN  apt-get update
RUN  apt -y upgrade
RUN  apt-get install -y python
RUN  apt install -y python3-pip
RUN  apt-get install -y libsnappy-dev

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN python3 -m pip install pip --upgrade
RUN python3 -m pip install pkgconfig
RUN python3 -m pip install kafka-python
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD python __init__.py
```

This is my python script that is throwing the error...

```
import multiprocessing
from kafka import KafkaConsumer


class Consumer(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self,host,topic,groupid):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.stop_event = multiprocessing.Event()
        self.topic = topic
        self.consumer = KafkaConsumer(
            bootstrap_servers=host,
            auto_offset_reset='earliest',
            enable_auto_commit=True,
            auto_commit_interval_ms=1000,
            consumer_timeout_ms=1000,
            group_id=groupid
        )
    def stop(self):
        self.stop_event.set()

    def run(self,topic,cb):
        self.consumer.subscribe([topic])
        while not self.stop_event.is_set():
            for message in self.consumer:
                cb(message.value)
                if self.stop_event.is_set():
                    break
```

I am positive the module is being installed by this line

`RUN python3 -m pip install Kafka-python`

But the script can't find it.

Comment: python3 install of your requirements and python(2) as your command?

Comment: Ohh my, thank you @mchawre